# Sklearn Regression model does not fit to specific part of a signal

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

iam facing the problem that my sklearn regressor of model type `HistGradientBoostingRegressor` (but the same problem also occurs with other types of regression models) does fit the truth signal ok but misses fitting a specific signal part. The image below shows the truth signal in green and the reconstructed signal of the model in red. One can see the "problem part" that i mean which is located between the first and the ~400th sample - these observations are just reconstructed by the model as a linear curve (constant):

[image]

The model is configured as shown below (the problem also occured whith other settings for the quantile loss, n_iterations and the learning rate):

```
HistGradientBoostingRegressor(loss="quantile",
                              quantile = 0.975,
                              max_iter = 10000,
                              learning_rate=0.01)
```

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried lowering the learning rate to 1e-3 or 1e-4 ?

Comment: Is this the training or the testing dataset?

Comment: The example above shows the training dataset. Reducing the learning rate ended in a massive underfitting.

Comment: @OrfeasBourchas  and  GaëtanLF do you have any ideas what i can try?

Comment: May be you need to change the number of bins in the e.g. ```HistGradientBoostingRegressor(bins=10)```. I think that the regressor bins the first 400 x elementh together since the y variable has very little variance for these values. Also, you can try to change the number of min_samples_leaf,max_depth, and max_leaf_nodes. Last but not least try to change your loss function to squared_error.

Comment: @OrfeasBourchas i will give'em a try. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @OrfeasBourchas i tried several changes (also including the hints of you) but the problem still exists. Do you have any other ideas for the reason why the line is approximated only as a constant?